# What is the point of having "x...n" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm just curious.

Arent both of the code snippets below doing the same thing? Why would someone want to use `...` instead of `..`, wouldnt `..` be easier to read?

```
for x in 1...11
     puts x
end

for x in 1..10
 puts x
end
```

Sorry if this is too subjective, I just dont understand why I would want to go from `1 to (n-1)` instead of `1 to n`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`10.5` is included in `1...11`, but not in `1..10`.

It's not `1 to n` vs. `1 to (n - 1)`, it's `1 <= x <= n` vs. `1 <= x < m`.

Comment: More precisely, there are an *infinite* amount of numbers which are included in `1...11` but not in `1..10`, namely all numbers which are greater than `10` but less than `11`. Given that there are infinitely many differences between the two, I'd argue that qualifies as "not doing the same thing".

Comment: Very nicely academically put, @Jörg. :)

Comment: @Joerg: Aren't there only a finite number of `Float`s between 10 and 11, at least in MRI/YARV?

Comment: @Andrew Technically speaking I suppose so, although I'd say the number is large enough to be practically infinite for most purposes. Mathematically, it's infinite. :)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the index in some data structure goes form 0 to struct.size() - 1. It's helpful then to have a way of saying this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
for i in 0 ... a.length
   puts a[i]
end
```

will print `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`. It you use the `..` form it will print an additional `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `n - 1`, then if `n` is 0, you would have `n - 1` of -1, which is used to indicate the end of an array.

```
array[0...0] # Returns no elements
array[0..-1] # Returns all elements
```